# Fast-loading image viewer (without double-buffering) to replace ACDSee?

Tags: software, image-review

Throughout the years, I have been looking for an image viewer to replace the ageing ACDSee 2.43 (classic). The key feature I'm looking for is the *perceived speed* of loading images, especially when paging through them: drawing partial images quickly, so it almost flies through a list, rather than waiting for the full image to load.

Is there another fast image viewer (mostly for jpegs) that doesn't use double-buffering, and draws a partial image while reading it from the disk?

Many programs I tried (like FastPictureViewer) claim to be fast, and they may well beat ACDSee on benchmarks, but in actual use they feel more sluggish in real use, since they need to repaint each image at once (due to double-buffering).

Comment: I wrote a viewer with ~300ms startup time and ~16ms between images (it preloads images). However, it does use double buffering. It's a hobby project and no one but me runs it. PM me if you want to try it.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest viewer for Windows is [PMView Pro](http://www.pmview.com) as far as I can tell. You can download a free trial for 30 days (IIRC) and the full version is not expensive ($50 USD). This may depend on your hardware but is one of the most efficient software at reading images.

I bought several licenses over the years and although I use Linux primarily, I still use it often from within VirtualBox. It is very fast and only slows down significantly for monstrous images such as 100+ MP panoramas.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Really surprised that they have a version for OS2!